# Fourier Series: Integral of a Sum or Sum of Integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

While touching on Fourier series in a PDEs course, our professor basically waved her hands at the concept that
$$
\int_0^a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin\frac{n\pi}ax\sin\frac{m\pi}ax\,dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\int_0^a\sin\frac{n\pi}ax\sin\frac{m\pi}ax\,dx=\frac a2A_m,
$$
claiming that an arcane knowledge of real analysis was required to prove this true for certain cases.

That explanation left me completely unsatisfied, as I then began to wonder about the kind of functions for which this is true or false.

I have some knowledge of real analysis, and a reference to this proof or a sketch of it would do wonders at resolving this mental craving that I have had since.

**Edit 1**: I added integration boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to declare over what region you are taking your integral over. Are you taking it over a closed bounded region? I am also assuming that the integer $m$ is fixed *a priori* yes? What about the coefficients $A_n$? Do you know anything nice about them (e.g. they are uniformly bounded in $n$)?

Replace the infinite sum of stuff with $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} s_k(x)$ where

$$s_k(x) = \sum_{n=1}^k A_n \sin(n\pi x/a)\sin(m \pi x/a).$$

Then you are asking why

$$\int \lim s_k(x) dx= \lim \int s_k(x) dx.$$

There are several circumstances when you can do this:

1. When the family $s_k(x)$ converges uniformly to something.
2. When the family $s_k(x)$ converges pointwise to something and is uniformly bounded (that's why I asked about the coefficients) - this is Arzelà's Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Note that for 1, if you are taking your integral over a compact set then I think it suffices to understand why the family $s_k$ is equicontinuous, which is where we need information about the $A_n$ as well.

Comment: The function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin(n\pi x/a)$ was obtained by solving a PDE and applying boundary conditions to it. Hence, the $A_n$ are aleatory integration constants. The integer $m$ is determined a priori and used this way to solve for $A_n$ in the equation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin(n\pi x/a)=g(x)$ by making use of the orthogonality of sines. I do not know what the domain of integration is, since all our professor did was multiply both sides by $\sin(m\pi x/a)$ and then integrate.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Funnily enough, it got accepted. : )

Answer (score 5):

You are actually considering $L^2$ (or something similar) convergence in this question. Not pointwise convergence. You use [Carleson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem) to extract the pointwise convergence as well.

What you are doing there is expanding the solution in terms of a basis for your space. If your space is $L^2[0, 2\pi]^2$ and your solution is $f$, you write your $f$ with respect to a basis $(e_n)$ of $L^2$ like
$$f(x) = \sum_n a_n e_n(x).$$
The convergence here is understood in *the norm*, that is$$\left \|f - \sum_{n = -N}^N a_n e_n \right \| \to 0$$
as $N \to \infty$. Your $(e_n)_n$ here are the $e^{i n x}$ as in Fourier series. This is your basis with properties such as
$$\int e_n e_m = \delta_{nm}.$$
Which means this is an orthogonal basis.

**Moral:** Convergence is not always meant to be pointwise.

Comment: If they keep upvoting you might get a badge for this! : ) (I think)

Comment: Could the question also be tagged harmonic-analysis?

Comment: @MattN. I don't think so. This is more PDE-like things.

Comment: @MattN. Badges are all I live for.

Answer (score 0):

Sum and integral is interchangable for *absolute convergent* series of *uniformly continuous* functions.